# Out of memory error whan loading images to memory

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am loading multiple images into my app. I have to load them all to use my animation.

```
    ArrayList<AnimationsCls> animArr = new ArrayList<AnimationsCls>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
             animArr.add(new AnimationsCls());

    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfimages; j++) 
        animArr.get(0).f_anim.addFrame(Drawable.createFromPath(path+"/Sites/Site6/Zoom1/Zoom"+j+".jpg"), i);    

    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfimages; j++) 
        animArr.get(1).f_anim.addFrame(Drawable.createFromPath(path+"/Landscape/Sequence10/Landscape_WB_"+j+".jpg"), i);    

    for (int j = 1; j <= numOfimages; j++) 
        animArr.get(2).f_anim.addFrame(Drawable.createFromPath(path+"/Sites/Site2/Zoom1/Zoom"+j+".jpg"), i);    


    public class AnimationsCls
    {
    AnimationDrawable f_anim = new AnimationDrawable();
    //AnimationDrawable b_anim = new AnimationDrawable();
    boolean active;
    }
```

The problem is that with 3 animation array the memory is sufucuent, but if I add more I get out of memory exeption. I already editet the images via Photoshop to minimum size, each image weights abput 90kb. Already added large heap to manifest. How can I reduce the size of images in memory without releasing them?

My memory in DDMS:

```
05-01 15:58:29.775: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.963MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.015: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.508MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.285: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.287MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.395: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.802MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.495: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.318MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.595: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.834MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.695: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.350MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.795: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.867MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:32.895: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 38.382MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.005: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 41.898MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.095: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 45.415MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.195: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 48.930MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.295: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 52.447MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.395: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 55.962MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.495: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 59.479MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.615: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 62.996MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.715: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 66.511MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.825: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 70.027MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:33.935: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 73.543MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.045: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 77.059MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.145: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 80.576MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.255: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 84.091MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.355: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 87.608MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.465: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 91.124MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.565: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 94.639MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.675: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 98.156MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.775: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 101.671MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:34.885: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 105.188MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.005: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 108.860MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.135: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 112.533MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.245: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 116.205MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.365: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 119.877MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.475: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 123.549MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.605: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 127.222MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.715: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 130.894MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.825: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 134.566MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:35.935: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 138.239MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:36.035: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 141.911MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:36.145: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 145.583MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:36.245: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 149.255MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 15:58:36.365: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 152.928MB for 3850256-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:11.075: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 152.960MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:11.745: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 156.573MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:11.975: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 160.088MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:12.175: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 163.605MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:12.415: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 167.121MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:12.595: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 170.637MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:12.805: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 174.153MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:12.995: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 177.669MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:13.195: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 181.185MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:13.375: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 184.701MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:13.555: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 188.217MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:13.725: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 191.733MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:13.905: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 195.250MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:14.085: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 198.765MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:14.315: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 202.282MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:14.525: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 205.798MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:14.755: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 209.314MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:15.005: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 212.830MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:15.205: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 216.346MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:15.415: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 219.862MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:15.615: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 223.378MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:15.815: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 226.894MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:16.025: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 230.411MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:16.255: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 233.926MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:16.475: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 237.442MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:16.655: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 240.958MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:16.855: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 244.474MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:17.085: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Grow heap (frag case) to 247.991MB for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:17.305: I/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3686416-byte allocation
05-01 16:19:17.345: E/dalvikvm-heap(13768): Out of memory on a 3686416-byte allocation.
```

Comment: should be careful adding large heap in manifest.The larger the heap more frequently gc kicks in. Worth having a look at the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: also have a look at the link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: How many images are you trying to add? If you are adding too many images or if the images are too big you will get out of memory exceptions like this

Comment: Many images :) How can I reduce their size in heap or enlarge the heap?